df.to_sql inconsistent invalid transation error message
I'm trying to upload data to a postgresql timeseries database.
My problem isn't a usual coding / engine one, but a logical one.
I have many dataframes, which are varying lengths.
For this example, say I have three - df1 df2 and df3, with lenths 800k, 100k and 120k
I can upload df1.to_sql('table_name', engine ... ) without issue.
When I try with df2, I get: sqlalchemy.exc.PendingRollbackError: Can't reconnect until invalid transaction is rolled back.  Please rollback() fully before proceeding (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/8s2b)
Then I try df3 and it works.
Now I have broken down df2 into many dataframes of equal length and realized that from 53000 onwards is the issue, and I cannot upload in large chuncks after 53000.
Now for the weird part.
Take a subdataframe of df2 composed only of rows 53000 to 55000.
I can upload them by chunks of 100 or 500 or 999, but not by chunks of 1000 or above.
Keeping in mind that for df1, I uploaded in chunks of 500k without issue, and that the data is the same!
Now I must be missing something, but I have no idea what.
Edit: the sql table is completely emptied every time I try to upload something, so it most likely isnt coming from a duplicate key or something of the sort. Also can't hurt to mention that I have two primary keys, one additional index column, and one column is a timestamp with timezone column.
After further tinkering, it seems the problem stems from the timestamp with timezone column. I understand they are the prefered storage format, but they really are a pain. If I revert to a timesamp without timezone, the code works. I'm stubborn so I'm going to try to figure out why, but if you have any ideas, let me know.

Do the postgres logs (or the SQLAlchemy echo output) show what caused the transaction to enter an invalid state?

ok i'm going to figure out what this means and get back to you

@snakecharmerb I looked at the echo from the engine and it doesn't show me much. It shows me the dictionary created to insert into the sql dataframe, and the last row is a commit row before the error triggers
